# Transaction handling by Container / Frameworks

Tags: spring, transactions, ejb

I am going through EJB, Spring and other such frameworks. In many places, it is mentioned that the Container / Framework will take care of "Transaction handling" and the developer can concentrate on business logic.

I would like to understand what the Container / Framework offers and what it takes care of on Transaction Handling. I understand it is much more than 'Commit / Rollback'.

P.S: Searched SO for similar questions, couldn't find any. Please close this question if this is already answered.

Comment: Thanks BalusC for the very quick response. Your answer in the other question is very detailed in the perspective of Commit / Rollback, the important feature of Transaction Management. I want to go a bit deeper and want to understand what else this covers or is it only about 'Commit / Rollback'.

Comment: In many books and reference materials, the term "Transaction handling will be taken care by XXXXXXX. Developer could concentrate on Business problems" is used. I would like to have a definite and concrete answer about this.

Comment: @BalusC: Is my understanding on this incorrect? Is Transaction handling only about 'Commit / Rollback'? If so, I would work on the answer based on your response in the other question.